# Implementing deprecated method - CLLocation

Tags: objective-c, xcode

With Xcode 9.3, I've a new warning.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

this method is now deprecated."Implementing deprecated method".
I've you got a solution ?
thanks

Comment: [Apple Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423716-locationmanager) will tell you to use `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Apple Documentation on `locationManager(_:didUpdateTo:from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423716-locationmanager) will tell you to use [`locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423615-locationmanager)

---

So for the new delegate `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)`, the documentation on the `locations` object states:

> locations
>
> An array of CLLocation objects containing the location data. This array always contains at least one object representing the current
>   location. If updates were deferred or if multiple locations arrived
>   before they could be delivered, the array may contain additional
>   entries. The objects in the array are organized in the order in which
>   they occurred. Therefore, the most recent location update is at the
>   end of the array.

Basically it means that there will be atleast 1 location in the array and if there are more than 1 then:

1. The last object in `locations` array will be the new/current location
2. The second last object in `locations` array will be the old location

Example (Swift 4+):

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let newLocation = locations.last

    let oldLocation: CLLocation?
    if locations.count > 1 {
        oldLocation = locations[locations.count - 2]
    }
    //...
}
```

Example (Objective-C):

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations {
    CLLocation *newLocation = locations.lastObject;

    CLLocation *oldLocation;
    if (locations.count > 1) {
        oldLocation = locations[locations.count - 2];
    }
    //...
}
```

---

*Ref:*

- *https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423716-locationmanager*
- *https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423615-locationmanager*

Comment: I've problem now with my CLLocation *currentLocation = locations; Because it's now an Array.

Comment: @pilou Updated answer

Comment: @pilou Updated answer with obj-c equivalent code :)